# Rate the app functionality in ios not working well

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, app-store

I am having an app in which I have a button to "Rate" the app.

On click of the button, I am using the following code.

```
- (IBAction)ratePressed:(id)sender
{


    NSString *str = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa";
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?", str];
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@type=Purple+Software&id=", str];

    // Here is the app id from itunesconnect 
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@appid", str];
    NSLog(@"str is %@",str);

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];

}
```

My App is not on the app store so when i Pressed the rate button it gives me an error saying

**Your request produced an error.
[new NullResponse]**

When I put the appid of of an app that is actually on the appstore. It works fine.

So can I put the custom message saying  "app is currently not available"? when the app is not on the appstore. Or is it a default message by Apple?

Please help me.

Comment: There is no need to change anything. This is only going to be used by users that have the live app so no one (except possibly an Apple reviewer) is going to see this error.

Comment: Actually, if it's been setup in iTunes, you can fetch the app's id, and use it in the url. Once the app will be live, rating should work accordingly. For testing, you may use the id of an app that's already on App Store. Your url seems fine, here's what I'm using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=%@", kAppId]`

Comment: BTW - why do you have all of those calls to `stringWithFormat`? Just use one for the whole string. `NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=%@", appId];`

Comment: Glad it's not working. This kind of stuff is obnoxious to users and shouldn't be in any app.